# Hands selection in a 6 table

Tags: starting-hand

I am trying to find any kind of cheat sheet that would guide me in which hands should I select to play in 6 players (Texas Hold'em) game.

I believe it will be needed to play more hands, but I am lost in which range we should be talking about.

Comment: Google finds a lot of those. You just need to know how to ask.
Try this one: http://bit.ly/1hLkwkg

Comment: Go here:  http://wizardofodds.com/games/texas-hold-em/, then click on 2-hand, 3-hand, 4-hand, 6-hand etc. to see the best starting hands for the corresponding game.  This is useful in developing a range for each of these situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good article on a basic range of hands used in the TAG style:

http://www.pokervip.com/school/poker-strategy/texas-hold-em-no-limit-beginner/tag-approach/

Basically your range is never fixed, you base your ranges on the style of play you are comfortable with and keep it flexible. One of the best things to do as a poker player is to change gears so whereas you may be a very tight aggressive (TAG) player in general if you find yourself on a table of players who always fold to aggression you should start becoming more of a loose aggressive player (LAG) by throwing more hands into your range.

The opposite is also true, if you find yourself on a table full of aggressive loose players, you should tighten your range and become more strong side weighted.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, a cheat sheet wouldn't be that great of an idea simply because there is no standard situation.
You could create a cheat sheet based on position but it all depends on how aggressive your opponents are and who raises preflop, how much he raises, in what position is that player, ...

There are just too many factors (parameters) which you have to consider when you make a decision whether to fold, call or raise.
In general you can play a little loser than on a full ring table (9 or 10 people) because not that many hands will be that strong. Under The Gun (first person after the blind) you could even try fancy stuff with a low ace or suited connectors. But then again, how does everyone else play on that table. Everything just depends on the situation you're in.

Comment: Thanks for the comment :) I knew this question would bring discussion like this, I was just wondering if somebody had a cheat sheet at least to base some of the decisions :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are playing microstakes there are a couple of Starting Hand Guides for Micro-Stakes 6-Max Games in Dan Harrington;Bill Robertie. Harrington on Online Cash Games; 6-Max No-Limit Hold 'em (Kindle Location 2270).

Comment: You should try to add more depth and therefore more value to your answers. I've seen you answer a lot of questions, but the quality of the answers could use some working. See other highly-upvoted answers/questions to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: i don't know what else i could have added. he asked for cheat sheets. there are 2 in the book.

Answer (score 0):

The basic rule I was taught was that you could loosen up an unsuited hand by one level for each person under ten at the table.

At a full table (10 people) you should not call "under the gun" (after the big blind) with anything less than AQ offsuit. With nine people, you can loosen that to AJ, with eight to AT, to seven to A9, and with six to A8 (offsuit). You can make comparable adjustments with other types of hands (all A-x suited are playable, all pairs are playable, etc.).

You can even make these adjustments in a 10-handed game as people fold in front of you. That is play AJ if the first person folds, AT if the first two people fold, etc.